# Flask-wtform case sensitivity issues

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I have a flask application with a user login system. I am now noticing some issues related to case sensitivity of the email address used to register and log into the site. **The TL;DR Question: How can I take the lower case of a Flask Form and use that to evaluate whether the user exists in my database?**

*Example*

Lets say user John Smith registers for an account on the site. He registers with John.Smith@gmail.com but then goes to log in with John.smith@gmail.com. As of now, the site will consider them to be two different users. I would like this to be the considered the same user.

In Python (my strength) I would just take `str(form.email.data).lower()` for the register form and then write that to the user table in the database. Then I would do the same when someone tries to log-in. In other words, I would always consider the lower case for register and login.

But I am struggling to implement this in Jinja, despite its Python similarities.

The email portion of register.html:

```
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ form.email.label(class="form-control-label") }}
                    {% if form.email.errors %}
                        {{ form.email(class="form-control form-control-lg is-invalid") }}
                        <div class="invalid-feedback">
                            {% for error in form.email.errors %}
                                <span>{{ error }}</span>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </div>
                    {% else %}
                        {{ form.email(class="form-control form-control-lg") }}
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
```

The register code in routes.py:

```
@app.route("/register", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(url_for('home'))

    form = RegistrationForm()

    admins = ['admin@admin.com',
              'admin@admin.com']


    if form.validate_on_submit():

        new_user_email = form.email.data.lower() ###<-----NOTE THAT THIS IS LOWER CASE
        admin_test = True if new_user_email in admins else False
        invited_test = Invites.query.filter(Invites.invited_email == new_user_email).count()
        print(admin_test, invited_test)

        if (invited_test == 0) & (admin_test == False): # Not invited and not and admin --> REJECT
            flash(
                'Sorry but it looks like you were not invited. Please contact a current member for an invitation.',
                'warning')
        elif (invited_test > 0) | (admin_test == True): ## if they have been invited OR if they are admin
            hashed_password = bcrypt.generate_password_hash(form.password.data).decode('utf-8')

            #create User object
            user = User(username=form.username.data.lower(), ###<----NOTE LOWER CASE
                        email=form.email.data.lower(), ###<----NOTE LOWER CASE
                        password=hashed_password)

            #write to db
            db.session.add(user)
            db.session.commit()

            #alert user
            flash('Welcome to. Enjoy the platform.', 'success')
            return redirect(url_for('login'))

        else:
            #Not invited condition
            flash('Sorry but it looks like you were not invited to __. Please contact a current member for an invitation.', 'warning')

    return render_template('register.html', title='Register', form=form)
```

The email portion of login.html:

```
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ form.email.label(class="form-control-label") }}
                {% if form.email.errors %}
                    {{ form.email(class="form-control form-control-lg is-invalid") }}
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                        {% for error in form.email.errors %}
                            <span>{{ error }}</span>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                {% else %}
                    {{ form.email(class="form-control form-control-lg") }}
                {% endif %}
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do this with python using the build in method lower().

In this example I'm using .lower() to make the entire email address lower case. You can also use `.upper()`. Which ever you choose just make sure it's constant site wide.
I'm using MongoDB but the same is if you were using SQLAlchemy. When you are capturing the form data `form.email.data` you just need to add the `.lower()` to make it all lower case.

**Login Route**

```
@app.route('/login/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    """Login Route"""
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(url_for('home'))
    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = Users.objects(email=form.email.data.lower()).first()
```

---

**Registration Route**

When a user registers on your site you want to do it when you are submitting the data to the database. In the registration route I also used .title() (FYI, .title will capitalize the first letter of every work and all others will be lower case) on the first name and last name fields. People have happy fingers and sometimes will type JoHN DOe, etc. This way it keeps first name and last constant. And, on the email address I used .lower().

```
@app.route('/register/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    """Registration Route"""
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(url_for('home'))
    form = RegistrationForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        hashed_password = bcrypt.generate_password_hash(form.password.data).decode('utf-8')
        add_new_user = Users(fname=form.data['fname'].title(), lname=form.data['lname'].title(),
                             email=form.data['email'].lower(), password=hashed_password)
```

Hope that helps :)